# English translation of Minkowski's Geometry of Numbers

Tags: reference-request

Is there an English translation of Minkowski's Geometry of Numbers? I have searched it but have found nothing.

Comment: A copy of the book in German is at https://archive.org/details/geometriederzahl00minkrich

Comment: Appreciated! I am still searching for an English translation :)

Comment: Maybe there's no such translation? Because the monograph is old fashioned and no one would like to spend time translating old stuff, though it may be the origin of a field.